# new task event not firing

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am programming an Outlook addin. It's working fine, but now I want to add an event handler when a user makes a new task.

For new contacts I am using this code and it's working.

```
cnt.ItemAdd += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(this.cnt_ItemAdd);
```

But for a new task this event is not firing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that

> But for a new task this event is not
>   firing

. Are you binding the task event to `cnt`? Maybe you should add the event to the **task** variable ( instead of **contacts** variable)

Comment: cnt was Outlook.Items but I took me to direction to solve the problem. But he was looking for items in contacts folder. Thanks